# Creating a setup script

Tags: windows, installation, windows-10

I don't even know how to ask this question, therefore I couldn't find anything that might help me.

I want to write some sort of script that downloads softwares, installs softwares(like eclipse), drivers, edit files(like configuration files) and more, so that a when a new developer comes to our company he will launch the script and he is set with all of our configurations.

What is the best way of doing it?
I am familiar with python, working on windows

Thank you very much!

Comment: That sounds like an installer/launcher. Unfortunately though, this question is way too broad for SO. If you needed help with something specific, we could help you there.

Comment: This has 2 upvotes? What programming problem in Python does it represent?

Comment: @roganjosh I was pretty close to flagging this post. Decided not to unless I saw a third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say there a several options, but none of them are cheap:

1. Switch to VMs and setup a default VM for developers with everything they need one time and distribute the snapshot to new employees. If something changes, change the snapshot and distribute it again.
2. There are some options to do this on real hardware, but I have never done this and according to this https://superuser.com/questions/716494/creating-a-snapshot-of-a-windows-7-system it is not a common way to go
3. Script everything by hand, make a lot of mistakes and take a lot of time ;) A python script can certainly do a lot of things, also can powershell or batch files. But it is a long way to go and it is very time consuming when a operating system updates or all of the sudden some installers do not support unintended installations anymore. I used to automate some installations in my job when I was a student and it really took some time and effort to maintain this all.

After all, this is more of a superuser.com question than stackoverflow, but maybe I could help anyhow.